# Возможно ли использовать замыкание, при арифметических операциях

Tags: javascript, замыкания

**Task:**

Есть простой [калькулятор](https://codepen.io/assylzhan91/pen/EJpjVo), который складывает два числа. Хочется сделать, чтобы  не только складывать, но и умножать, вычитать, делить,  даже делить по модулю.  При вводе в поле

`<input type="button" name="symbol" value="">`

символ оператора (*, -, +, /, %) выполнял арифметику. Я полагаю, что здесь как-то используют замыкание.

Просьба, опишите подробно, пожалуйста, почему в данном примере стоит  использовать closure или наоборот  не уместно,возможно есть другие варианты??

*я добавил новый `input` ниже в исходнике, по сравнению от предыдущего по ссылке*

**Source:**

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="num1" value="">
    <input type="button" name="num2" value="="> 
    <input type="button" name="symbol" value=""> <--!добавленный ТЭГ-->

    <input type="button" name="calc" value="=">
    <span class="result"></span>
</div>
```

---

```
let btn = document.querySelector('input[name=calc]');
let num1 = document.querySelector('input[name=num1]');
let num2 = document.querySelector('input[name=num2]');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
let symbol = document.querySelector('.symbol'); //новое выражение

btn.addEventListener('click', totalSum);

function totalSum() {


}
```

Comment: Замыкание - это сохранение контекста (переменных) бывшего в момент создания функции. Оно не может никаким образом относится к арифметическим операциям. Вам надо в функции, которая сейчас складывает, явно получить символ операции и сделать ветвление (скорее всего switch) который в зависимости от символа выполнит ту или иную операцию

Comment: Так вам хочется сделать отдельные кнопки для каждой операции или один инпут, куда вручную печатаются символы "+", "*", "-" и исходя из них проделывать операцию? (так-то можно сделать <select><option> на самом деле... с возможностью выбрать нужную опцию)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME да-да, когда ввожу нужный оператор, чтобы выполнялось арифметика!!  В этом примере я просто хочу продумать логику, а не с точки зрение разумности какой тег будет семантичнее(если есть такое слово)

Comment: @Mike  а если через this

Comment: @John this это не оператор, а указатель на текущих объект. А никаких объектов у вас тут нет и в помине. Чудес не бывает, если вы явно не напишите `if(sym=='+') { x=a+b } else if(sym=='-') { x=a-b } ...` ничего само не произойдет

Comment: Сообщение аффтару: в ответ добавлена версия с отдельными кнопками. Но это всё еще остается тренировочной игрулькой... Все калькуляторы на компах-мобильных примерно одинаковые, потому что это и есть самый удобный вариант) В идеале надо пробовать стандартный калькулятор повторить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделал под отдельные кнопки:

[JsFiddle ДЕМО](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/7nmd0wk4/)

Там же подробно описал все шаги.
Хотя в целом, eval() рекомендуют использовать только в крайних случаях... здесь мне понравилось это решение, но не стоит им разбрасываться везде)

---

Старый ответ решил не трогать:

---

С простыми операциями легко, потому что их запись в JS соответствует напечатанному символу, а символ "%" означает "посчитать остаток после деления".

Есть функция `eval()`, которая может взять любую строку и выполнить её как код. Поэтому сперва можно записать операцию в виде строки с помощью `Sting()`...

[JsFiddle ДЕМО](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/oxwv6182/)

```js
(function(){
  const opera = document.getElementById('opera');
  const num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
  const num2 = document.getElementById('num2');
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  const result = document.getElementById('result');

  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   //символ == означает сравнение значений. 
   //Берем значение выбранного символа и сравниваем с "%"
   if( opera.value == "%" ) {
     result.innerText = (Number(num1.value)*Number(num2.value))/100 ;
   } else {
      //Вот здесь по сути записано (число) + (символ операции) + (число)
      //Если у нас введено 7 * 5 то записанное равно строке "7*5"
      result.innerText = eval( String(num1.value + opera.value + num2.value) );
   }
  });
})();
```

```css
#opera option {font-size:30px;}
#opera,#btn,#result {font-size:30px;}
input {font-size:30px;width:200px;}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<select id="opera">
  <option>+</option> 
  <option>-</option> 
  <option>*</option> 
  <option>/</option> 
  <option>%</option> 
</select>
<input type="number" id="num2">
<br><br>
<button id="btn">=</button>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: у меня получилось! весь день голову напрягал, и не напрасно! Зацените :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот, чего я хотел добиться [откорректировал]

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('input[name=calc]');
let symbol = document.querySelector('input[name=symbol]');
let num1 = document.querySelector('input[name=num1]');
let num2 = document.querySelector('input[name=num2]');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');

btn.addEventListener('click', addition);
symbol.addEventListener('input', writeSymbol);
num2.addEventListener("input", btnEnable);
num1.addEventListener("input", btnEnable);

function addition() {
    let a = parseInt(num1.value);
    let b= parseInt(num2.value);
    let res;

    if (symbol.value === "+"){
        res = a + b;
    }

    else if(symbol.value === "*"){

        res = a * b;
    }

    else if(symbol.value === "-"){

        res = a - b;
    }

    else{
        alert('incorrect symbol')
    }

    result.textContent = res;
    btn.disabled = true;

}

function writeSymbol(){
    this.setAttribute("value", this.value);
    btn.disabled = false;
}

function btnEnable(){
    btn.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="num1" value="">
  <input type="text" name="symbol">


  <input type="text" name="num2" value="">
  <input type="button" name="calc" value="=">
  <span class="result"></span>
```

Comment: Первый if кстати лишний) let res и так равно их сумме. Если при загрузке изначально выбор будет стоять на сумму, то оно и так посчитает res. А if для измаенения res уже можно начать с '*' [здесь можно == вместо ===] // к слову, onclick, oninput и подобное - могут принимать единичные значения. Для одной кнопки не может быть несколько onclick (как не может быть несколько отдельных style="..." style="...") - в приоритете будет последний. Тут в принципе не мешает, но если код очень большой, иногда нужно на одну кнопку несколько кликов повесить... потому рекомендуют писать через addEventListener )

Comment: @ OPTIMUS PRIME спасибо за замечание! Дело в том, что не мог найти альтернативу на событие oninput для addEventListener, может подскажете!

Comment: Там почти везде то же самое, только убрать on → ...addEventListener('click', function() { ... }); вместо 'click' могут быть → input (запускает функцию при вводе текста), change (при изменении фокуса с элемента), mouseover (при наведении курсора), keyup (тот же инпут, только срабатывает при нажатии вообще любой кнопки), mouseenter (как только мышка заходит в область внутри элемента), mouseleave (покидает)... из того что вспомнил.